# VISUAL STUDIO XAMARIN FROMS

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual

tengo una duda cada vez que abro un archivo para que se me carguen los 3 que serían de `Android` y `iOS` y el otro no me carga el último antes de abrir me aparece que no se cargaron los proyectos y no se poruqé me sale este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: ]]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y que dice la ventana de salida?? porque seguro hay un error mas detallado...

Comment: No trabajo con Xamarin pero imagino que en algún lado debe tener un log donde diga que pasa